# PhantomJS.Org takes too long to respond against my phantom js script?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I have a simple script I got from *"Getting Started with PhantomJS"* book.

```
var system = require('system');
   var url = system.args[1];
   var page = require('webpage').create();
   page.open(url, function(status) {
     if ( status === "success" ) {
       console.log("Page is loaded.");
       phantom.exit(0);
} });
```

When I run a command like "phantomjs chapter2.js http://www.google.com" I get the correct response of "Page is loaded". Same with facebook.com

It's funny because the book told me to run "phantomjs chapter2.js http://www.phantomjs.org", but all it does is hang on me for a minute before the script stops and goes back to the command prompt without printing anything back.

Is it a problem on my end with my internet connection?

Comment: The `www.` subdomain of `phantomjs.org` is a [dead end](http://isup.me/www.phantomjs.org).  Remove the `www.` and it [should work](http://isup.me/phantomjs.org).

Comment: Holy cow that worked! You should reply here and I'll mark your answer as correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `www` subdomain of `phantom.js` is a dead end: http://isup.me/www.phantomjs.org

Remove the subdomain and it'll work as expected: http://isup.me/phantomjs.org

Comment: Thank you for explaining that to me. It seems weird because I never thought of www as a subdomain. I thought it's something that's just part of the http:// url therefore not optional. I learned something new today. If I build more rep points, I'll come back and upvote this if I can remember to do so!

Answer (score 0):

The page http://www.phantomjs.org does not resolve.

http://isup.me/www.phantomjs.org shows a dead end.

Comment: That is exactly right. However, Mr. Llama answered this earlier so I have to give him the correct answer. Still, thank you.